# Soql IN Operator

Tags: soql

This query works until adding WHERE clause, What's issue? Thanks!

```
Select Id, Name, 
    (Select ParentId, Name From Obj__r), 
    (Select Name From Contacts) From Account
WHERE Id IN (Select ParentId From Obj__r)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error message that you're seeing.

Comment: Anonymizing your code makes it more difficult for answerers to provide you with accurate responses. I've added an answer because I can see what most of the problem is, but it's not entirely clear.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I got it to work after changing Obj__r in WHERE to Obj__c.  So why it uses the object name and not relationship name as in the Select clause for the same sub-query to the same child object of Account?

Comment: @DCL Because you aren't querying through a relationship. The subselect is not a child query.

Comment: To the person who downvoted - why? The question was reasonable, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE Id IN (Select ParentId From Obj__r)
```

This is certainly wrong in at least one way, but possibly more than one since this is not the actual text of your query.

A semi-join sub-select, which is what this is, is not a child subquery and would never use a relationship name (`__r`). Rather it would directly query the object, with either `__c` or no suffix if the object is standard.

But if this object has a non-custom `ParentId` field, it must be a standard object, so you should not either not have a suffix on the object name, or have one on the field name.